# Missing requirement when using carrierwave and fog to upload file to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I got this error `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`. That seems weird because I already added carrierwave.rb in initializers folder. The access/secret key works perfectly when I use **aws-sdk**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: ENV["PUB-KEY"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["SEC-KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV["mybucket"] 
end
```

Comment: When do you get this error? In production? In development? Are you sure that your `PUB-KEY` and `SEC_KEY` are set consistently across environments?

Comment: In development. as I mentioned, with aws-sdk gem I uploaded successfuly to s3

Comment: Does the aws-sdk gem use the same ENV vars in its config? Can you include your working config for aws-sdk?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what my working one looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

For production, I added the keys `S3_KEY`, `S3_SECRET` and `S3_BUCKET`. For development and testing, I used an initializer that is in a `.gitignore` file:

```
# .gitignore
/config/initializers/app_environment_variables.rb
```

and in the initializer

```
# config/initializers/app_environment_variables.rb

ENV['S3_KEY'] = "********************"
ENV['S3_SECRET'] = "**************************..."
ENV['S3_BUCKET'] = "**********-dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

Production and development configurations are different. 
You need to put AWS keys in development too.

I just copied AWS keys from

```
config/environments/production.rb
```

to

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

And everything worked fine.