# Rails: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, fog, figaro-ruby

This error has been asked about before but I have tried all the answers on here and none have worked.

I am trying to connect AWS s3 to rails:

and I am getting the error pasted at the bottom of this question.

carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:      ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],     # required
    aws_secret_access_key:  ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], # required
    region:                 ENV['AWS_REGION'],            # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'

  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'discoveredfmyelpdemo'                          # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

I used figaro for my environmental vaiables which installed successfully and created application.yml (Note hashes are to cover up key but are correct in file):

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "A########################SA"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "ba####################st"
AWS_REGION: "Sydney"
development:
    AWS_BUCKET: discoveredfmyelpdemo
production:
    AWS_BUCKET: discoveredfmyelpdemo
```

I don't know why this should affect it but just in case I will give you my gem and uploader relevant file contents (I am new to ROR).

Avatar_Uploader.rb:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "fog-aws"
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'figaro', '1.0'
```

and this is the full error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.38.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.38.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.38.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.38.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.38.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-98d73a935047/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:123:in `eager_load_fog'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-98d73a935047/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:136:in `fog_credentials='
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/initializers/fog.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-98d73a935047/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:158:in `configure'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-98d73a935047/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/initializers/fog.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the output when you put this variable in console: `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']`

Comment: @NaimRajiv, command not found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098275/missing-requirement-when-using-carrierwave-and-fog-to-upload-file-to-s3

Comment: @amtest Hi thanks for the link but as I said in the beginning I already tried all the other links. I was trying for four hours before posting.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

application.yml

```
aws_access_key_id: "A########################SA"
aws_secret_access_key: "ba####################st"
aws_region: "Sydney"
development:
  aws_bucket: discoveredfmyelpdemo
production:
  aws_bucket: discoveredfmyelpdemo
```

and to access `ENV['aws_access_key_id']` like that

Can you try the keys in yml files in small letters instead?

Comment: Hi @Sebin, did that still the same.

Comment: Hey @NicholasMuir Can you try with small case letters inside application.yml file as in the updated answer?

Comment: yeah tried that, still the same. Also you had "was" instead of "aws" in two lines of that answer I changed back to "aws", I assume that correct.

Comment: @NicholasMuir yeah, that `was` were autocorrected. Can you make sure you are not using any tab characters in your `yml` file? Indent using double spaces.

Comment: yep made sure, no tabs just spaces.Still the same.

Comment: May be this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35596825/1684772. Try killing spring process and start application.

Comment: I am really sorry I couldn't help you out. I am not sure this is related, but shouldn't the region name be `ap-southeast-2` instead of `Sydney`?

Comment: Thank for all your effort, I will check that as well.